# Detect and notify when download is complete

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I am having a drive link to download a zip file. When I click on the link, the download starts in the browser. Once the download is completed, I want to send an email to notify the user. Is it Possible. I have a .net application(C#) and a page that shows all the drive links. Once a drive link is clicked and gets downloaded completely, I want to send the mail. Also if the download fails in between, I want to send the failed email. Can I do that?

Comment: @apllied ai, Following link may help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the below reference code. Add a proper download url link and try this out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;
            }

            svg:not(:root) {
              display: block;
            }

            .playable-code {
              background-color: #f4f7f8;
              border: none;
              border-left: 6px solid #558abb;
              border-width: medium medium medium 6px;
              color: #4d4e53;
              height: 100px;
              width: 90%;
              padding: 10px 10px 0;
            }

            .playable-canvas {
              border: 1px solid #4d4e53;
              border-radius: 2px;
            }

            .playable-buttons {
              text-align: right;
              width: 90%;
              padding: 5px 10px 5px 26px;
            }
        </style>
        
        <style type="text/css">
            .event-log {
    width: 25rem;
    height: 4rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: .5rem;
    padding: .2rem;
}

input {
    width: 11rem;
    margin: .5rem;
}

        </style>
        
        <title>XMLHttpRequest: progress event - Live_example - code sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
            <div class="controls">
    <input class="xhr success" type="button" name="xhr" value="Click to start XHR (success)" />
    <input class="xhr error" type="button" name="xhr" value="Click to start XHR (error)" />
    <input class="xhr abort" type="button" name="xhr" value="Click to start XHR (abort)" />
</div>

<textarea readonly class="event-log"></textarea>
        
        
            <script>
                const xhrButtonSuccess = document.querySelector('.xhr.success');
const xhrButtonError = document.querySelector('.xhr.error');
const xhrButtonAbort = document.querySelector('.xhr.abort');
const log = document.querySelector('.event-log');

function handleEvent(e) {
if (e.type=='progress')
{log.textContent = log.textContent + `${e.type}: ${e.loaded} bytes transferred Received ${event.loaded} of ${event.total}\n`;
    }
else if (e.type=='loadstart')
{
log.textContent = log.textContent + `${e.type}: started\n`;
}
else if  (e.type=='error')
{
log.textContent = log.textContent + `${e.type}: error\n`;
}
else if (e.type=='loadend')
{
log.textContent = log.textContent + `${e.type}: completed\n`;
}

}

function addListeners(xhr) {
    xhr.addEventListener('loadstart', handleEvent);
    xhr.addEventListener('load', handleEvent);
    xhr.addEventListener('loadend', handleEvent);
    xhr.addEventListener('progress', handleEvent);
    xhr.addEventListener('error', handleEvent);
    xhr.addEventListener('abort', handleEvent);
}

function runXHR(url) {
    log.textContent = '';

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   addListeners(request);
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.responseType = 'blob';
        request.onload = function (e) {
        var data = request.response;
        var blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.href = blobUrl;
        downloadLink.download ='download.zip';
        downloadLink.click();
        };
        request.send();
        return request
}

xhrButtonSuccess.addEventListener('click', () => {
    runXHR('https://abbbbbc.com/download.zip');
});

xhrButtonError.addEventListener('click', () => {
    runXHR('http://i-dont-exist');
});

xhrButtonAbort.addEventListener('click', () => {
    runXHR('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/content/main/files/en-us/_wikihistory.json').abort();
});
            </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

The download link works for zip files as well.

Reference:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/progress_event#live_example